# User-defined function with lapply function

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm attempting to establish a user-defined function that inputs predetermined variables (independent and dependent) from the active data frame. Let's take the example data frame `df` below looking at a coin toss outcome as a result of other recorded variables:

```
> df
  outcome toss    person  hand age
1       H    1      Mary  Left  18
2       T    2     Allen  Left  12
3       T    3       Dom  Left  25
4       T    4 Francesca  Left  42
5       H    5      Mary Right  18
6       H    6     Allen Right  12
7       H    7       Dom Right  25
8       T    8 Francesca Right  42
```

The `df`data frame has a binomial response `outcome` being either heads or tails and I am going to look at how `person`,`hand`, and `age` might affect this categorical outcome. I plan to use a forward-selection approach which will test one variable against `toss` and then progress to add more.

As to keep things simple, I want to be able to identify the response/dependent (e.g., `outcome`) and predictor/independent (e.g., `person`,`hand`) variables before my user-defined function as such:

```
> independent<-c('person','hand','age')
> dependent<-'outcome'
```

Then create my function using the `lapply` and `glm` functions:

```
> test.func<-function(some_data,the_response,the_predictors)
+ {
+     lapply(the_predictors,function(a)
+         {
+         glm(substitute(as.name(the_response)~i,list(i=as.name(a))),data=some_data,family=binomial)
+     })
+ }
```

Yet, when I attempt to run the function with the predetermined vectors, this occurs:

```
> test.func(df,dependent,independent)
Error in as.name(the_response) : object 'the_response' not found
```

My expected response would be the following:

```
models<-lapply(independent,function(x)
+ {
+     glm(substitute(outcome~i,list(i=as.name(x))),data=df,family=binomial)
+ })
> models
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = substitute(outcome ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), 
    family = binomial, data = df)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)        personDom  personFrancesca       personMary  
      1.489e-16       -1.799e-16        1.957e+01       -1.957e+01  

Degrees of Freedom: 7 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
Null Deviance:      11.09 
Residual Deviance: 5.545    AIC: 13.55

[[2]]

Call:  glm(formula = substitute(outcome ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), 
    family = binomial, data = df)

**End Snippet**
```

As you can tell, using `lapply` and `glm`, I have created 3 simple models without all of the extra work doing it individually. You may be asking why create a user-defined function when you have simple code right there? I plan to run a `while` or `repeat` loop and it will decrease clutter.

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know code only answers are deprecated but I thought you were almost there and could just use the nudge to use the `formula` function (and to include 'the_response in the substitution):

```
 test.func<-function(some_data,the_response,the_predictors)
 {
     lapply(the_predictors,function(a)
         {print(   form<- formula(substitute(resp~i,
                                             list(resp=as.name(the_response), i=as.name(a)))))
         glm(form, data=some_data,family=binomial)
     })
 }
```

Test:

```
> test.func(df,dependent,independent)
outcome ~ person
<environment: 0x7f91a1ba5588>
outcome ~ hand
<environment: 0x7f91a2b38098>
outcome ~ age
<environment: 0x7f91a3fad468>
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = form, family = binomial, data = some_data)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)        personDom  personFrancesca       personMary  
      8.996e-17       -1.540e-16        1.957e+01       -1.957e+01  

Degrees of Freedom: 7 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
Null Deviance:      11.09 
Residual Deviance: 5.545    AIC: 13.55

[[2]]

Call:  glm(formula = form, family = binomial, data = some_data)

#snipped
```

Comment: Brilliant! I am slowly understanding the `substitute` function but I'm glad I was not too far off course. Good to find out about the `formula` function as well. Thank you!

Comment: Would you have any recommendations for performing this same procedure with combinations of variables. For instance, `outcome~person+hand` and `outcome~person+age`. I understand the idea of not providing a coded answer so the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you should be searching for "all subsets regression". It is, of course, one of the many discredited methods of "data dredging".

Comment: Was there a reason for removing the acceptance checkmark? If you think my negative comments about the statistical strategy are wrong, you should step up and dispute them,. The place to really have it discussed properly would be CrossValidated.com

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance. I had seen individuals do such things when a question was extended as to gather attention. Your checkmark is rightfully restored. Thank you for speaking up addressing the issue, and providing the appropriate approach. My updated question was restored to my original question as to prevent confusion. Again, I apologize for the inconvenience.